# Nesting an each loop within an ERB rendered layout is not iterating over any elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I have a common sublayout that I use on many pages in my application. To render it, I use `render layout: ...` and then put the rest of the view in the block:

```
<%= render layout: 'layouts/content-box', locals: { header: 'Foo' } do %>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= post.inspect %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This produces an empty template, in fact the loop does not iterate at all. This used to work, but we are currently moving from HAML:

```
= render layout: 'layouts/content-box', locals: { header: 'Foo' } do
  - @posts.each do |post|
    = post.inspect
```

I thought that the HAML I have posted was the equivalent, but obviously not. If I move the loop outside of the `render` block, then it works. The array is there and populated. What am I doing wrong? I have tried using `<%- @posts.each %>` as well (notice the hyphen). Nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Gahhhh, it was because the layout that I was trying to render was still a HAML file. Once I converted it to an ERB as well, everything worked as expected.